how do we add a button that shows in google meet page on the left side of audio if our extension is installed?
I am developing a Chrome extension that adds a button to the left side of the audio control in Google Meet. The button should only be visible if our extension is installed. I have tried adding the button using the following code, but the button is not visible.
<button id="my-button" class="gm-button gm-button-flat gm-button-secondary gm-button-size-medium">
  My Button
</button>

#my-button {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const button = document.createElement('button');
  button.id = 'my-button';
  button.classList.add('gm-button', 'gm-button-flat', 'gm-button-secondary', 'gm-button-size-medium');
  button.textContent = 'My Button';
  const audioControl = document.querySelector('.gm-video-control');
  audioControl.insertBefore(button, audioControl.firstChild);
});


This code should be in a content script. Assuming you already did that, remove the DOMContentLoaded line and optionally re-inject files from content_scripts so that the button appears immediately after installing/updating/reloading the extension in Chrome.
